# How to route on the basis of dropdowns selection in angular4?

Tags: angular, routes

Based on two dropdowns- Brand and Product, How to route to a component and display item.

Like dropdown1 contains - HP, Samsung, etc
dropdown2 contains - TV, Fridge, Radio etc

Navigation should be like if- 'HP' is selected from dropdown1 and "Laptop" from dropdown2 and when 'Submit' button is clicked then

```
addressbar(url) should look like- /ListPage?BrandName=HP&ProductType=Laptop
```

or, for Single dropdown selection:-

```
addressbar(url) should look like- /ListPage?ProductType=Tv
```

or,

```
addressbar(url) should look like- /ListPage?BrandName=HP
```

### filter.component.html

```
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <angular2-multiselect *ngIf="dropdownList" [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event,'brand')"
        (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
      </angular2-multiselect>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <angular2-multiselect  *ngIf="dropdownList1" [data]="dropdownList1" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems1" [settings]="dropdownSettings1" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event,'product')"
        (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)" (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
      </angular2-multiselect>
    </div>

<div class="col-xs-2 filterControls">
    <button  type="button" (click)="getFilters()" label="Done" class="ui-button-success" icon="fa-check" style="height: 28px;margin: 5px;border-radius: 3px;">Submit</button>
    <button  type="button" (click)="resetFilters()" label="Reset" class="ui-button-danger" icon="fa-refresh" style="height: 28px;margin: 5px;border-radius: 3px;">Reset</button>
  </div>
```

### filter.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html'
})
  getFilters() {
alert(this.selectedItems); //item selcteddropdown{"id":"2","listName":"Samsung"}
    console.log(this.selectedItems1)
    this.router.navigate( []);  <------ how to Navigate
  }
```

### Dashboard.component.html

```
<app-filter></app-filter>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

### dashboard.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'displaydefault', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {  path: 'displaydefault', component: displayComponent},
   {  path: 'displaySelection', component: displaySelectedComponent} <--- logic 
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use query params. Like this:

```
getFilters() {
  const BrandName = this.selectedItems.listName;
  const ProductType = this.selectedItems.listName;

  const queryParams = {
    BrandName,
    ProductType
  }

  this.router.navigate([], { queryParams });
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the router in a template:

```
<a
 [routerLink]="'/ListPage'"
 [queryParams]="myParamsObject"
>
```

Or you inject the Router to your component and use it in your code:

```
  this.router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: returnUrl } });
```